# how to handle the kubernetes dead processing deployment

Tags: kubernetes

After I am using this command to force delete the deployment pod:

```
➜  .kube kubectl delete pod cruise-web-768b5b89f-5d6zb -n reddwarf-pro --grace-period=0 --force
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
pod "cruise-web-768b5b89f-5d6zb" force deleted
```

the kubernetes deployment status are always processing and the status never changed, the deployment pod number did not changed forever. where is going wrong? what should I do to handle this situation? This is the version info:

```
➜  .kube kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.0", GitCommit:"ab69524f795c42094a6630298ff53f3c3ebab7f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-07T18:16:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:53:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.23) and server (1.21) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

this is the dead deployment:

[image]

this is the cruise-web describe:

```
➜  .kube kubectl describe deployment cruise-web -n reddwarf-pro
Name:                   cruise-web
Namespace:              reddwarf-pro
CreationTimestamp:      Wed, 03 Aug 2022 18:52:14 +0800
Labels:                 app=cruise-web
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=cruise-web
Replicas:               2 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:       app=cruise-web
  Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2022-08-03T19:06:12Z
  Containers:
   cruise-web:
    Image:      registry.cn-hongkkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/cruise-web:fa736797790ef42b2658717f1d2b653fc78ef716
    Port:       80/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      APOLLO_META:  <set to the key 'apollo.meta' of config map 'pro-apollo-config'>  Optional: false
      ENV:          <set to the key 'env' of config map 'pro-apollo-config'>          Optional: false
    Mounts:         <none>
  Volumes:          <none>
Conditions:
  Type          Status  Reason
  ----          ------  ------
  Available     False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing   False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
Events:         <none>
```

this is the get pods output:

```
➜  .kube kubectl get pods -n reddwarf-pro
NAME                                     READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
admin-service-859f6c9bd5-m875t           1/1     Running       0          39h
consul-1630121482-0                      1/1     Running       9          76d
consul-1630121482-1                      1/1     Running       11         76d
consul-1630121482-2                      1/1     Running       7          76d
dolphin-dict-service-6996f955f9-fq7s7    1/1     Running       0          38d
dolphin-gateway-5c9ddc444-gbfdz          1/1     Running       0          19d
dolphin-music-service-69f8fc9f76-c722l   1/1     Running       1          71d
dolphin-post-service-76b6495544-9zlmw    1/1     Running       0          41h
fortune-service-67fdf7f544-5whm4         1/1     Running       0          41d
official-website-776b6c6dfd-lp747        1/1     Running       0          5d11h
react-admin-5667d49bf6-f7bdp             1/1     Terminating   0          163d
react-admin-new-6db65cc97d-xgz4t         1/1     Running       0          37h
react-admin-new-7d5c446fb9-5vpmb         1/1     Terminating   0          91d
rust-learn-c5f5bd9c-w8fhs                1/1     Terminating   0          93d
time-capsule-service-67b458f584-blzlz    1/1     Running       0          3d12h
```

and I check the deployment shows info that `replicaset xxxxxx has timeout processing`, then I tried to show the describe of replicaset:

```
➜  .kube kubectl describe replicaset cruise-web-768b5b89f
Error from server (NotFound): replicasets.apps "cruise-web-768b5b89f" not found
```

Comment: anything in describe for deployment? `k describe deployment cruise-web` and `k get pod`, the pod might be pending state or crashing which is why its showing `0/1`

Comment: and also how much time it take to your pod to get healthy

Comment: i do not see any running from for this deployment controller, so seems like replica issue `k describe replicaset replica_name`

Comment: the replicaset was not found, what should I do? @Adiii

Comment: Try scale the deployment to zero, check and scale up by 1, check again. Why you force delete at the beginning?

Comment: how is the service deployed? manifest file? and also `k get replicaset ` first to see if the name is different

Comment: I have already tried this way, the deployment always have 1 pod that never end. @gohm'c

Comment: Because the record is still in etcd. The is the result of force delete. Can you elaborate a bit why you decided to force delete?

Comment: because the pod in terminating status for a long time, then I can not wait it to end, so I forced to delete the pod.@gohm'c

Comment: Since you are allowed to scale to zero, you can delete the deployment and re-apply.

Comment: seems the only way to solve this problem.@gohm'c

Comment: or may trigger the scale `kubectl scale --replicas=2 deployment cruise-web` or rollout `kubectl  rollout restart deploy -n cruise-web`

Comment: the scale to 2 I have already tried. @Adiii

Comment: if rollout did not help then its time to check Kubernetes event

Comment: `...terminating status for a long time` - what's the value for your `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` in the spec?

Comment: `kubectl get events` after executing scale command.